# Auth0 - get Token from Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, auth0

I'm, using Auth0 to create and save the user on the server.

How can I access to the valid token anywhere in my app after the user is logged in?

```
var strategy = new Auth0Strategy({
    domain:       'foo.eu.auth0.com',
    clientID:     'xxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    callbackURL:  '/login'
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
    // accessToken is the token to call Auth0 API (not needed in the most cases)
    // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token
    // profile has all the information from the user
    var id_token = extraParams.id_token;
    return done(null, profile, id_token);
  });
passport.use(strategy);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

module.exports = strategy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep the `access_token` ? What will you be doing after user authenticates?